# Using recursion to getNth position for Racket

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket, radix

I have to write a recursive call in Racket that allows us to get the Nth position of a given list. for example (getNth 3 '(1 2 3 4)) should return back 4 and if the list is empty or if the position is non existent then return and empty list.

this is my code:

```
(define getNth
   (lambda (ls)
     (if (= ls null?) 1
         (getNth ls(append '(car ls)(cdr ls))))))
```

getting this error:
   getnth: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 1
  given: 2
  arguments...:
   4
   ()

if you need the recursive statement here it is:

base case-getNth N LS) = (), if LS = null

recursive call -(getNth N LS) = (getNth N (append '(car LS)(cdr LS))), if N >= 1

im getting stumped I dont know how to implement this one.

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10603919/2809078).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get an item from a list at a given index in racket language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523361/how-do-i-get-an-item-from-a-list-at-a-given-index-in-racket-language)

Comment: FYI a nice racket-y way of checking for empty is (empty? list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your getNth can revieve a "N" from a list (rather than a fixed N i.e. get3rd), your are indeed missing an argument:

```
(define getNth                     
   (lambda (n list)                   
      (cond ((null? list) '())             
            ((= n 0) (car list))              
            (else (getNth (- n 1) (cdr list))))))
```

Which basically is until I get to the number I want, decrement the it and "pop" the first element out until the first element of the list is the one I want i.e. the rest of the list.

Your lambda only takes one argument the way you defined it which is exactly the error message you're having ;)

I think I appropriately balanced my parenthesis :)

A trick with recursion: it's generic concept is easy:

A recusrion is "if a terminal condition occurs, I'm done, return appropriate value. Else, increment the argument toward termination condition and call myself with these new arguments"

It gets complicated when the termination condition can have exceptions. Because if your can't trivially expressed it as "if this done else redo with increment" you could make mistakes...

Comment: thanks for the info I saw where I went wrong but u think i did another thing wrong I used your code but fro some reason it will give me back the list again instead of whats in that position.

Comment: I fixed the code. It could be improved by using the else cond syntax instead of the #t one... (fixed the double if version)

Comment: okay now its showing the proper positions now do you know how to shw up an empty lis when n isnt in the list? i think that what the top code is. but it keeps showing an error.

Comment: There I fixed it. It's getting ugly :/ there's probably a more idiomatic way to do it but I'm more used to lisp than scheme...

Comment: yea its cool i just dont like the teachers at my school when it comes to teaching comp sci. they dont do a good enough job explaining the language so implementation gets hard.

Comment: In the case of scheme, you're 50 pages shy of the whole thing ;)

Comment: but what does pair check cause I was never really definite on how that worked.

Comment: The lists are build as a sequences of pairs. An empty list is a non-pair. (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3))) => '(1 2 3). In lisp, you would simply test for list (if list (car list) (print "empty")).

Comment: I fixed the function to make it as idiomatic as I could. replaced the (not (pair list)) with (null? list) predicate and put the last condition as an else instead of another cond #t

Comment: You are missing some parentheses so it won't work as intended. Even the indentation agrees.

Comment: You fixed a bug I didn't see.. Currently, when n is zero it does two things, (car list) and recurse. If n is not zero it returns an undefined value.

Comment: You still lack a closing parens. Indentation still agrees so you should see that your else term is not on it's own. Try testing it.

Comment: Ok I thought the else had to be part of the 2nd cond statement. It's a third one. which is such the else is equivalent to #t :P fixed hopefully for the last time ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with you code..

1. You say you need a procedure that takes two arguments, but yours take only `ls`.
2. When `ls` is the empty list the result is `1`
3. if list is not empty you recurse  with two arguments, both lists. The first is the same as the original argument which would make a infinite recursion. The second is an append between `'(car lst)` which evaluates to the list `(car lst)` and `(cdr ls)` (the the list `ls` except the first pair)

```scm
(define get-nth
  (lambda (index lst)
    (if (= index 0)            ; when index is zero
        (car lst)              ; return the first element
        (get-nth (- index 1)   ; else recurse with the decrement of index
                 (cdr lst))))) ; and all but the first element (the rest) of lst

;; test
(get-nth 0 '(a))   ; ==> a
(get-nth 1 '(a b)) ; ==> b

;; However, this won't work:
(get-nth 0 '())       ; will fail
(get-nth 10 '(a b c)) ; will fail
```

I kind of like the fact that it doesn't work when given wrong arguments. `list-ref` and `car` fails just as much if gived wrong parameters, but that is easy to fix:

```scm
(define get-nth
  (lambda (index lst)
    (cond ((not (pair? lst)) '())        ; it should always be a pair
          ((= index 0) (car lst))        ; when index is zero, return the first element
          (else (get-nth (- index 1)     ; else recurse with the decrement of index
                         (cdr lst))))))  ; and all but the first element (the rest) of lst
```

Instead of just th empty list you can have a default value or perhaps throw an error with  `(raise 'get-nth-error)` (R6RS+)

Comment: i tried frilling in the blanks got this error :mcar: contract violation
  expected: mpair?
  given: ()

Comment: I tried filling in the blanks as such : getnth (- index 1) (cdr lst)))))

Comment: when I put in an empty list it says error. when its empty i need it to send back an empty list same is the nth number isnt in the list. but your code does get most of it out the way and i thank you deeply for that.

Comment: @AdamSpencerBaker That is what my last part is all about. A `get-nth` function demands there is a list which has at least `(+ index 1)` elements so just like `(car '())` will fail so will `(get-nth 0 '())` or `(get-nth 10 '(a b))`. If you want I can show how I would have added a `if` or switched to `cond` since it's a nice `if-elseif` form.