# Matrix Manipulation in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I need to write a function that produces the nth column of a matrix in Racket without using recursion. For example `(list (list 1 2 3) (list 2 3 4) (list 6 7 9))` if I wanted the 2nd column I would receive `(list 2 3 7)`.

I tried `(append (map (lambda (n) (list-ref (list-ref M) n) n)) M))`, but it keeps showing me an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523361/how-do-i-get-an-item-from-a-list-at-a-given-index-in-racket-language

Comment: Use `map` with a function (i.e. use lambda) that calls `list-ref`.

Comment: edits must not invalidate the existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attempted solution uses `list-ref` twice, which is not needed, and one of those calls does not have enough arguments: `(list-ref M)` has the function taking only one argument, but it requires two arguments -- a list and an integer.

The `list-ref` function will return an indexed element from an input list, so `(list-ref '(1 2 3) 1)` will return `2`. Consider what `map` will do here: the matrix is represented as a list of lists (a list of rows), i.e., as `((1 2 3) (2 3 4) (6 7 9))`. The `map` function will act on the members of the input list, which are the lists `(1 2 3)`, `(2 3 4)`, and `(6 7 9)`. By `map`ping the `list-ref` function over that input, you can take whichever element you want from the sublists. So, `(map (lambda (row) (list-ref row 1)) '((1 2 3) (2 3 4) (6 7 9)))` would evaluate to `(2 3 7)`, as desired.

Here is a function that lets you take any column from a matrix:

```
(define (nth-column M n)
  (map (lambda (row) (list-ref row n)) M))
```

Sample interactions:

```
scratch.rkt> (define M '((1 2 3)
                         (2 3 4)
                         (6 7 9)))
scratch.rkt> (nth-column M 1)
'(2 3 7)
scratch.rkt> (nth-column M 0)
'(1 2 6)
scratch.rkt> (nth-column M 2)
'(3 4 9)
```